# No module named pond.tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I am trying to train a network following this [blogpost](https://github.com/koenvanderveen/privateml/blob/master/image_analysis/Convnet.ipynb).

The import statements looks like this.

```
from pond.tensor import NativeTensor, PublicEncodedTensor, PrivateEncodedTensor
```

I couldnot run this code, as i am not able to find this "pond.tensor". 
Can anyone help understanding this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is from the package https://github.com/koenvanderveen/privateml/blob/master/image_analysis/pond/tensor.py

one level up from where your file is.